# Laravel Socialite LinkedIn additional info to handler

Tags: laravel, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement login/register a user using a LinkedIn profile. It is working fine, but users can register as employers or as candidates on my web app. Can I somehow implement the "role" field, when it redirects me to the handler that I have that info if a user is trying to register as a candidate or as an employer?
I need that info because it is a mandatory field in my registration.

I have these routes:

```
Route::get('/linkedin', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\LoginController@redirectToLinkedin');
Route::get('/linkedin/callback', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\LoginController@handleLinkedinCallback');
```

And this is my redirectToLinkedin function:

```
public function redirectToLinkedin()
{
    return Socialite::driver('linkedin-openid')->redirect();
}
```

I am using:

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"laravel/socialite": "^5.10",
"php": "^8.0.2",
```